# Consecutive Axios calls using an array

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I have a function that when it gets called, it cycles through an array where each item makes an Axios request, gets the response and updates the state.  I'd like to be able to do these requests one after the other since each one is changing the state.  I've tried a few things such as using axios.all/axios.spread but haven't been able to figure out how to apply that dynamically.  Any help would be much appreciated!

The function makes a request that searches for a pdf of a contract based on the contractId.  It returns an object called portfolio which contains an array of contracts.  In essence, my screen is displaying a table of contracts and when the Find Files button is clicked, each contract is updated row by row on the screen.

```
findFiles = () => {
  const contracts = this.state.portfolio.contracts;
  contracts.map(contract => {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://localhost:57821/Portfolio/FindFile?contractId=" + contract.contractId
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ portfolio: res.data });
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a simple reduce operation on your array:

```
contracts.reduce((promise, next) => promise.then(() => {
    axios.get(
        "http://localhost:57821/Portfolio/FindFile?contractId=" + contract.contractId
    ).then(res => {
         this.setState({ portfolio: res.data });
    })
), Promise.resolve()).then(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution above is valid or you can create a method that acts in more explicit way:

```
const axios = require('axios');
function makeRequestsFromArray(arr) {
    let index = 0;
    function request() {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/' + index).then(() => {
            index++;
            if (index >= arr.length) {
                return 'done'
            }
            return request();
        });

    }
    return request();
}

makeRequestsFromArray([0, 1, 2]);
```